# In WSO2 EI / ESB how do I process array/object based query parameters? (i.e. with square brackets)

Tags: wso2, query-string, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have an API that uses query parameters as follows:

```
/events/search
  ?title=royal
  &area=southeast
  &maint[date]=20180823
  &maint[user]=oscar
  &maint[action]=release
```

(line breaks added for readability)

Processing the simple query params within WSO2 EI is straightforward. There are a few ways to do this using the [property mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Property+Mediator):

- `<property name="title" expression="get-property('query.param.title')"/>`
- `<property name="title" expression="$url:title"/>`
- `<property name="title" expression="$ctx:query.param.title"/>`

However, I have been unable to process the array/object based query params. I have tried to use the [property mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Property+Mediator) in various ways, non of which work:

- `<property name="maintDate" expression="get-property('query.param.maint[date]')"/>`
- `<property name="maintDate" expression="get-property('query.param.maint.date')"/>`
- `<property name="maintDate" expression="$url:maint[date]"/>`
- `<property name="maintDate" expression="$url:maint.date"/>`
- `<property name="maintDate" expression="$url:maint&#91;date&#93;"/>`
- `<property name="maintDate" expression="$url:maint%5Bdate%5D"/>`

Has anyone had an experience and any success in this area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ESB API URL template will look like below:

```
uri-template="/test?title={t}&amp;area={a}&amp;maint[date]={date}&amp;maint[user]={user}&amp;maint[action]={action}
```

You can access the square bracket query params as below:

```
<property name="date" expression="$ctx:uri.var.date"/>
<property name="user" expression="$ctx:uri.var.user"/>
<property name="action" expression="$ctx:uri.var.action"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Saad, this solved the problem. One thing to add is that I needed to encode the left and right square brackets in the uri-template as these were being encoded by the tool I was using to test (i.e. maint%5Bdate%5D={date}).

Comment: As a follow-up question, what if the query parameters are optional? I understand one way to allow for optional query parameters is to use the uri-template "/test*", however I am then unable to 'name' each of the query parameter values using the 'maint[date]={date}' definition suggested.

Comment: I tried in several ways to access values of box bracketed query params when query params are optional, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Thank you for trying, much appreciated!